# Replacing the MicrosoftAjax.js referenced in aspx pages in ASP.NET with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

The HTML/JS .aspx pages in my ASP.NET application use the [MicrosoftAjax.js](https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.2/1/MicrosoftAjax.js) file like :

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
```

Considering MicrosoftAjax.js is very old, I want to replace the AJAX file with jQuery and serve the same purpose. I am a bit not clear how complex this change would be and its impact as I am not much familiar with JQuery.

Are there any specific steps that i can follow to do these change ?

Comment: Could be pretty complex, depending on how much MS AJAX is used. Sounds like you should just leave it, TBH. It works, and by the way, it's not just for XMLHTTP-type things, MS AJAX serves several purposes, for ex, ScriptManagers and UpdatePanels use it.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery and Microsoft Ajax are two different libraries, and if you're using one, it will probably be complicated to switch to the other one, but it really depends on how much you're using it. As wazz commented, if you're using an updatepanel, you can't just use that with jquery. So if you're using it with any .NET controls, you'll want to find alternatives for those, and then if you have any custom javascript using ms ajax, you'll have to figure out how to rewrite it in jquery.

Overall, if you're concerned about out-of-date technologies you're probably better off upgrading the site out of webforms entirely if that's an option for you, rather than trying to just update this single aspect.

Answer (score 1):

To meet these requirements, it's necessary a hard work job: The best practice for migrate this case is creating a new Visual Studio Web Forms Project assembly, and migrating one-by-one aspx page: for each aspx page, you create a new aspx at new project, copying only region with controls (and following a copying code-behind too). After this steps, you need to substitute each javascript logic routines that consumes [MicrosoftAjax.js](https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.2/1/MicrosoftAjax.js) to routines that consumes JQuery library.